# ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function - Product pages do not work - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

I've been having some trouble with M2.4 after an upgrade from 2.3.5.

Getting this error on product pages only, backend and all other pages seem to work fine.

I have used

rm -rf generated

rm -rf var/cache

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

& nothing helps.

`ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\AdaptAssignStatusToProductPlugin::beforeAssignStatusToProduct(), 2 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 121 and exactly 3 expected in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Plugin/CatalogInventory/Helper/Stock/AdaptAssignStatusToProductPlugin.php:71`

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\AdaptAssignStatusToProductPlugin->beforeAssignStatusToProduct(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#2 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Helper/Stock/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\Interceptor->___callPlugins('assignStatusToP...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/AddInventoryDataObserver.php(37): Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock\Interceptor->assignStatusToProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#7 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(581): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(1098): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->_afterLoad()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(605): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->_afterLoad()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntityLoad.php(34): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->afterLoad()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntityLoad->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntityLoad), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#15 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(119): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\Catalog...', 'load_after', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '89', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(716): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '89')
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(540): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), '89', NULL)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load('89')
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('load', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}('89')
#24 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php(308): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->load('89')
#26 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->getById('89', false, NULL, false)
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php(270): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->getById('89')
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php(228): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->loadVariationByFallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php(205): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable->getProductVariationWithMedia(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php(247): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable->_getAdditionalConfig()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php(154): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable->getJsonConfig()
#32 /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml(9): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable->getJsonConfig()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(273): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(303): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/v...')
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php(481): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php(459): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable->getHtmlOutput()
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php(125): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable->_toHtml()
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1111): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable->_toHtml()
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/LockGuardedCacheLoader.php(136): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1133): Magento\Framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader->lockedLoadData('BLOCK_fcf09c021...', Object(Closure), Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php(449): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php(471): Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable->toHtml()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getProductDetailsHtml(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callParent('getProductDetai...', Array)
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Plugin/ProductDetailsBlockPlugin.php(37): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): PayPal\Braintree\Plugin\ProductDetailsBlockPlugin->aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#50 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getProductDetai...', Array, NULL)
#51 /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml(1): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getProductDetailsHtml(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(273): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(303): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/v...')
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1111): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1115): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
#57 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(566): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('category.produc...')
#60 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#61 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#62 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('category.produc...', true)
#63 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(522): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('category.produc...', true)
#64 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php(100): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('product_list')
#65 /var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml(1): Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View->getProductListHtml()
#66 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#67 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(273): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View), '/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#68 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(303): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/v...')
#69 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1111): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#70 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1115): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
#71 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#72 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(566): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#73 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('category.produc...')
#74 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#75 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('category.produc...')
#76 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('category.produc...', false)
#77 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('category.produc...', false)
#78 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#79 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#80 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#81 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#82 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false)
#83 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#84 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#85 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#86 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#87 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false)
#88 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#89 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#90 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#91 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#92 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false)
#93 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#94 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#95 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#96 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#97 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false)
#98 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#99 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#100 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#101 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#102 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#103 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#104 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#105 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#106 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#107 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(963): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#108 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#109 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#110 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#111 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#112 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#113 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#114 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#115 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#116 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#117 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#118 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(120): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#119 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#120 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#121 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#122 {main} [] []

I've checked file permissions, all owned by the 'magento_user' who is a member of the www-data group, all files set to 755/644 according to the doc's. Turned dev mode off & on again, cleared cache, recompiled etc but still the product page throws up this error, anyone have an idea?

Using debian 10, php7.4 (but happens with 7.3 too), elastic search seems to be installed ok & shows v7 when asked, I'm at a loss now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. The plugin method signature is:

```
public function beforeAssignStatusToProduct(
    Stock $subject,
    Product $product,
    ?int $status
): array
```

This means the third argument is not optional, but it can accept a null value.

However, in the only place the original `Stock` class is used there is no `$status` argument passed at all.

`\Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\AddInventoryDataObserver`:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
        $this->stockHelper->assignStatusToProduct($product);
    }
}
```

---

So it leaves us the only easy option to fix that - copy the core plugin class file to our own namespace, make the third argument optional and override the original plugin via DI preference.

Another option would be to override the observer from above and explicitly pass a `null` value as a second argument, but that would give less confidence since some 3rd party modules might also use the `Stock` class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Magento 2 root directory.

And run these all commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
chmod -R 777 var/*
```

Thanks

Comment: Do NOT do this unless you are on your local machine or a dev server

Comment: I've run

rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/cache
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

so many times i could do in my sleep, & I'd rather not use 777